# MVC How to pass data from view to model using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-4

Hello I'm posted a question asking what to use to send information from a view to a model. I realize that the info needs to be send to the controller and then to my model. I got some code that send info from my view to my controller:

Here is the Ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#cmdSend").click(function () {
        // Get he content fom the input box
        var mydata = document.getElementById("cmdInput").value;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Terminal/processCommand",
            data: { cmd: mydata },  // pass the data to the method in the Terminal Contoller
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function (e) { alert(e); }
        })
    });
});
```

An this is the code in my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult processCommand(string cmd)
    {
        return Json(cmd);
    }
```

I've tested it and send my input in json. However my problem is, I don't know how to take the string out of that and send it to my model. Please any help would be appreciated.

Comment: _"I want to be able to send commands using Ajax/JQuery/Json"_ -- That sounds like the solution I'd choose. Where are you stuck?

Comment: Slight nitpick on terminology... You don't pass data "from the view to the model."  You pass data from the client to the server by invoking controller actions and sending data to those actions (often in the form of a model, but any argument type would work).  AJAX simply invokes these actions via JavaScript instead of page loads (which is what you want).  The controller then handles the action accordingly, possibly interacting with a model server-side in some way.

Comment: I don't know the code specific for communicating data directly from the view to the model, I've searched for a sort of "type and enter" similar to what a terminal is like and I found that Ajax/JQuery/Json are the way to go about it but I don't know how to use them for the particular scenario.

Comment: I would recommend starting at http://learn.jquery.com, maybe even jumping forward to the ajax section. As stated, I think your question is too broad for SO.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments to your question, the terminology you use is a little confusing, but if understood your question correctly, you want an action on your controller on the server to accept a 'command' and work with it.

The following post can be made, in order for the ajax post to successfully hit the action :

```
$('#cmdSend').click(function () {
    var cmdInput = document.getElementById('cmdInput').value;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'terminal/sendInfo',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {cmd : cmdInput},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            //What you want to do with the returned string with data.cmd
        }
    });
});
```

The controller action would be like the following :

```
public class TerminalController : Controller
{
   [HttpPost]
   public JsonResult sendInfo(string cmd)
       {
           //Do what you want to do with 'cmd' here.

           return Json(new { cmd = "Whatever you want to send" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
       }
}
```

Hope this helps!